# Vite React Project .env variable not changing value

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm doing a React project using Vite and I'm having a problem with my .env variable. Currently it is set like this

```
VITE_API_URL=http://localhost:8080
```

and I access it using: `import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL`

But recently, I need to change the value of this variable but I see that the old value is still being used regardless of what I do. I tried resetting the project, computer, using npm cache clean --force and deleting the .vite folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's weird. Try closing all the terminal and run the dev server again by `npm run dev`. Also try removing browser's cache.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out it only happens when I run it in the VS Code terminal. Using Windows Powershell solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Same on my Mac M1. I had this issue when running from VS Code's terminal, but when I switched to a normal one it started working. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Something with the terminal is caching those .env values, I don't know if that's technically what's going on. But killing the terminal instance and running the process again from a new terminal should bring in the latest values.